# Error in updating rows Google Sheets API

Tags: c#, google-api, google-sheets

I try to update rows in Google Sheets, but have error 403

> Request had insufficient authentication scopes. [403]
>       Errors [Message[Request had insufficient authentication scopes.] 
>       Location[ - ] Reason[forbidden] Domain[global]]

```
UserCredential credential;

        using (var stream =
            new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-dotnet-quickstart.json");

            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
            Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
        }

        // Create Google Sheets API service.
        var service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
        });

        List<object> list1 = new List<object>() { "Item", "Cost", "Stocked", "Ship Date" };
        List<object> list2 = new List<object>() { "Wheel", "$20.50", "4", "3/1/2016" };
        List<object> list3 = new List<object>() { "Door", "$15", "2", "3/15/2016" };
        List<object> list4 = new List<object>() { "Engine", "$100", "1", "30/20/2016" };
        List<object> list5 = new List<object>() { "Totals", "=SUM(B2:B4)", "=SUM(C2:C4)", "=MAX(D2:D4)" };
        IList<IList<Object>> list = new List<IList<Object>>() { list1, list2, list3, list4, list5 };

        ValueRange VRange = new ValueRange();
        VRange.Range = range;
        VRange.Values = list;


        SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.UpdateRequest upd = service.Spreadsheets.Values.Update(VRange, spreadsheetId, range);
        UpdateValuesResponse response = upd.Execute();
        Console.WriteLine(response.UpdatedRows);
```

Answer (score 2):

Google caches the validation so once you approve the client via the browser pop up, it won't appear again. However, when you change the scopes it doesn't check, it just continues to use the already approved (stored) credential, whatever those previous permissions may be.

The sample code does mention this in a comment:

> If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
>            at ~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-dotnet-quickstart.json

Since you're writing to `System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal`, it'll show up in your /Documents folder, under `.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-dotnet-quickstart.json` per the `Path.Combine`. Delete that file (or the folder if you like) and make sure to use `static string[] Scopes = { SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets };`, it will prompt you again now and you should be all set.

Comment: Yeah that's the solution that worked for me, delete the credentials folder in `My Documents` under the `.Credentials` folder.

Comment: Hi, I could not find the .Credentials folder in Documents folder. Is the location changed for new apis?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the line where you define Scopes in your code, but make sure you're not requesting the READONLY scope

Comment: I corrected scopes on `static string[] Scopes = { SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets };`but it doesn't work again

Comment: Are you able to perform read functions? Is the Drive Api  enabled in the dev console?  Could also try remaking the oauth token.